# If $x, y \in [0,10]$ then what is the number of solutions $(x, y)$ of the inequation $3^{sec^2x - 1} \sqrt{9y^2-6y+2} \le 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality

How do we solve the following question?

> If $x, y \in [0,10]$ then what is the number of solutions $(x, y)$ of the >inequation $3^{sec^2x - 1} \sqrt{9y^2-6y+2} \le 1$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$\sec^2x-1=\tan^2x\ge0$ for all real $x$

$\implies 3^{\sec^2x-1}\ge3^0$

and $(3y-1)^2+1\ge1$ for real $y$

Answer (score 1):

i would use that
$$(\sec(x)^2-1)\ln(3)+\frac{1}{2}\ln(9y^2-6y+2)\le 0$$ after taking the logarithm on both sides

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-We have
$$\sqrt{9y^2-6y+2}\ge1\text{ and just in }x=\frac13\text{ is equal to 1}$$

$$3^{\tan^2(x)}\ge1\text{ and is equal to 1 when }  x=k\pi;\space k\in \mathbb Z$$